# The third line isn't showing up for some reason

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time
import math
for i in range(9):
  if math.remainder(i, 3) == 0:
    print('Processing.')
    time.sleep(0.5)
  elif math.remainder(i, 3) == 1:
    print('Processing..')
    time.sleep(0.5)
  elif math.remainder(i, 3) == 2:
    print('Processing...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Output:

```
Processing.
Processing..
Processing.
Processing..
Processing.
Processing..
```

What did I do wrong? Why won't the line with three "."s show up? What's wrong with it?

```
Processing.
Processing..
Processing...
Processing.
Processing..
Processing...
Processing.
Processing..
Processing...
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

`math.remainder(2, 3)` returns `-1.0`, as it returns the difference from the *closest* integer multiple, not the leftover after removing as high a whole multiple as possible (it's not "remainder" as normally taught in school). It's rarely what you want. Just use the operator form:

```
for i in range(9):
  if i % 3 == 0:
    print('Processing.')
    time.sleep(0.5)
  elif i % 3 == 1:
    print('Processing..')
    time.sleep(0.5)
  elif i % 3 == 2:
    print('Processing...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Mind you, the final test isn't necessary since `i` is always an `int`, and the first two tests exclude all other options, so you could just replace `elif i % 3 == 2:` with `else:`.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. Basically there are three ways to solve it: i % 3 == 2:; math.remainder(i, 3) == -1:; and else:.

Answer (score 0):

This code works so it might be a `math.remainder()` problem.

```
import time
for i in range(9):
  if i%3 == 0:
    print('Processing.')
    time.sleep(0.5)
  elif i%3 == 1:
    print('Processing..')
    time.sleep(0.5)
  elif i%3 == 2:
    print('Processing...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

If you're not familiar with mod it means find remainder.

Comment: Got it. From the response above, I learned that math.remainder gives you the closest integer which includes negative integers. Thank you for responding.